# Dalvik mess with library code and project cannot runs anymore

Tags: android, adt, dalvik, android-library

After updating ADT and Android SDK on my machine, all my projects get errors.

Now I have this:

PS: This error happens when running the project that have a jar as dependency (it was compiled with proguard and we dont have the original sourcecode to compile it again).

```
W/dalvikvm(3497): VFY: unable to resolve static field 994 (storeicon) in Lcom/ww/dgs/R$drawable;
D/dalvikvm(3497): VFY: replacing opcode 0x60 at 0x0042
W/dalvikvm(3497): VFY: unable to resolve static field 987 (libraryicon) in Lcom/ww/dgs/R$drawable;
D/dalvikvm(3497): VFY: replacing opcode 0x60 at 0x0060
W/dalvikvm(3497): VFY: unable to resolve static field 1069 (mainframe) in Lcom/ww/dgs/R$layout;
D/dalvikvm(3497): VFY: replacing opcode 0x60 at 0x00b1
I/dalvikvm(3497): DexOpt: unable to optimize static field ref 0x0467 at 0x16 in Lcom/ww/sharedlibrary/e;.a
D/AndroidRuntime(3497): Shutting down VM
W/dalvikvm(3497): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x400f8760)
E/AndroidRuntime(3497): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(3497): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.ww.dgs.R$layout
E/AndroidRuntime(3497):     at com.ww.mainframe.MainFrame.onCreate(Unknown Source)
E/AndroidRuntime(3497):     at com.ww.iba.DigiMag.onCreate(DigiMag.java:27)
E/AndroidRuntime(3497):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1048)
E/AndroidRuntime(3497):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1715)
E/AndroidRuntime(3497):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1767)
E/AndroidRuntime(3497):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:122)
E/AndroidRuntime(3497):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1005)
E/AndroidRuntime(3497):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/AndroidRuntime(3497):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:132)
E/AndroidRuntime(3497):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4028)
E/AndroidRuntime(3497):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(3497):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
E/AndroidRuntime(3497):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:844)
E/AndroidRuntime(3497):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:602)
E/AndroidRuntime(3497):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
I/dalvikvm(3497): threadid=4: reacting to signal 3
I/dalvikvm(3497): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
```

The code from com.ww is inside a jar that I used on the other builds.

Comment: Do you use proguard? After I updated my ADT and SDK I had to download proguard again from their website to make my projects work again.

Comment: No this project doesn't use proguard

Comment: Did you tried cleaning the projects and also using: Android Tools->Fix Project Properties?

Comment: I did refreshig, cleaning, "Android Tools > Fix Project Properties" more than once. None helps.

Comment: If the jar was compiled with proguard its likely the same case as SeRPRo

Comment: I cannot recompile it, we don't have the source of the library

Comment: Can you please include the full output of the dx tool from your build? Seeing how it fails at runtime is helpful but it'll be even more helpful to know how dx put this together.

Comment: +1 for interesting question, AFAIK, the obfuscated jar file should only be used as publish/release stage, there is no way you can easily use it as a library dependency in another project at development stage. Keen to see if someone can provide a solid answer for this.

Comment: it always gives you hard time updating ADT or tools :-( It couldn't find links to any external libs attached :-(

Answer (score 1):

I am getting this too now and am able to get around it by removing all external jars from the project.  You can add them back in after it's been cleaned. I'm assuming you have access to the original project source code...

Rightclick on project, go to Java Build Path, and remove all external jars other than your Android libs. Then clean.

Comment: I don't have the original source code of the library I'm using (it's only the jar)

Comment: oy... well then I'm all out of ideas :(

Comment: Currently, the Facebook android SDK causes this crash

Answer (score 0):

Got this error after updating to the Android Platform Tools preview 15 rc5 and Android Tools 21 rc5, plus running the "check for updates..." in eclipse.

LogCat error

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.someapplicationlibrary.lib.R$layout
```

Eclipse compiler error:

```
Errors occurred during the build.
Errors running builder 'Android Pre Compiler' on project 'myApplication'.
String index out of range: -51
Errors running builder 'Android Pre Compiler' on project 'someapplicationlibrary'.
String index out of range: -54
```

Tried to revert to the stabel Android Tools... but ending up with even more errors.

My solution was to load the workspace in a eclipse version that was not updated with the "check for updates..." in the eclipse Help menu.

Then it compiled correct, and the application worked again, hope this helps:)